# How to pipe an HTTP response to a file in Go?

Tags: go

How do I convert the below code to use streams/pipes so that I don't need to read the full content into memory?
Something like:
`http.Get("http://example.com/").Pipe("./data.txt")`

```
package main
import ("net/http";"io/ioutil")

func main() {
        resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
        check(err)
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        check(err)
        err = ioutil.WriteFile("./data.txt", body, 0666)
        check(err)
}
func check(e error) {
        if e != nil {
                panic(e)
        }
}
```

Comment: The response of Get contains a field Body hat implements Reader. You can basically just pass this to some sort of function that writes its contents into your file. At no point the whole content of the body is loaded into the memory, except if you request that.

Comment: more important to check the resp.StatusCode is 200.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

How about `io.Copy()`?  Its documentation can be found at: http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy

It's pretty simple, though.  Give it an `io.Reader` and an `io.Writer` and it copies the data over, one small chunk at a time (e.g. not all in memory at once).

So you might try writing something like:

```
func main() {
  resp, err := http.Get("...")
  check(err)
  defer resp.Body.Close()
  out, err := os.Create("filename.ext")
  if err != nil {
    // panic?
  }
  defer out.Close()
  io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
}
```

I haven't tested the above; I just hacked it together quickly from your above example, but it should be close if not on the money.

Comment: Note that this code doesn't check the error returns of either of the `Close()` statements.

Comment: @Nick that's pretty common (even idiomatic), though, to defer close and ignore the error. There's usually not much you can do on a close error except scream at the OS.

Comment: @PuerkitoBio deferring `Close` and ignoring the error is not good practice even if it is common! In this particular case use the `check` function from the OP, eg `defer check(resp.Body.Close())` and `defer check(out.Close())` should do the trick.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood Well, I was talking about production code that tries to recover from an error. If "error handling" means panic, I agree that it can be done the way you mention. Otherwise, except for logging the error, not much you can do (as discussed here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/sfo0tvPIDuk/c5UnGvoty1EJ).

Comment: Here is [checkClose](https://github.com/ncw/swift/blob/master/swift.go#L114) which shows how you can check errors on a deferred close. Don't ignore errors on close if you value your data integrity! If close returns an error you need to report it to the user. From the Linux man pages: Not checking the return value of close() is a common but nevertheless serious programming error. It is quite possible that errors on a previous write() operation are first reported at the final close(). Not checking the return value when closing the file may lead to silent loss of data.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood: in all seriousness, I do not see the point of that checkClose function.  It retrieves the error.  Close returns the error.  Why do you need a function to get it?

Comment: You use it so you can `defer checkClose(io, &err)` - it will then alter the return code of the returning function to indicate an error happened in the close, [giving the convenience of a defer but returning errors properly](https://github.com/ncw/swift/blob/master/swift.go#L345).

Comment: I see now.  That's why you checked for existing errors before overwriting it: so that you are only reporting close errors if there weren't, for example, open or write errors.  I can see how that's good practice.  I've drunk the idiom Kool-Aide.

Comment: Please forgive the necro, but I got a notification from this question and after being reminded of it, I recalled something new I've learned in the meantime.  `defer check(out.Close())` will not work as intended because the arguments passed to `check()` are evaluated immediately, closing the file.  What you'd want is a check function that takes a pointer to the file and closes it in the body, or even a func literal, such as `defer func() { if err := out.Close(); err != nil { /* handle error */ }()`

Comment: I'm amused that there was a lot of comments about not checking for errors on `Close()` (a good idea!) but no one mentioned the (arguably) more important failure to check the error return from `io.Copy`.

Comment: As of Go 1.16, the call to io.Copy in this answer uses [File.ReadFrom](https://golang.org/pkg/os#File.ReadFrom) under the covers.  A nice feature about using io.Copy is that io.Copy uses the best available copy mechanism.  It's better to use io.Copy than pick a lower-level copy function on your own.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is [File.ReadFrom](//golang.org/pkg/os#File.ReadFrom):

```
package main

import (
   "net/http"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   r, e := http.Get("http://speedtest.lax.hivelocity.net")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer r.Body.Close()
   f, e := os.Create("index.html")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer f.Close()
   f.ReadFrom(r.Body)
}
```