# Transfer a big file in golang

Tags: go

Client send file, the size may be more than 5G, to slave server, and than slave send to master server.

Will the slave save temp file to itself? I do not want it happen because it will slow the upload speed and waste the slave's memory.

Any way to avoid this? And what is the best way to transfer a big file in golang?

Comment: If your slave works as a relay, can it just have a limited buffer space (filled from sender and consumed by receiver connections), and refuse to receive any more if it fills up?

Comment: Is this an http server?

Comment: Both slave and master are http server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there's a standard way to avoid store-and-forward approach: as soon as a client connects the slave server the latter should open a connection to the master server and then just *stream* the data from the client there. Typically this is done using the `io.Copy()` function.  Thanks to Go's excellent duck typing using interfaces, this works for TCP connections and HTTP requests/responses.

(To get better explanation(s) you have to narrow your question down.)

A part of the solution does even appear in the similar questions suggested by stackoverflow—[here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16311368/720999).

Comment: I use io.copy(), but meet the [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234755/io-copy-cause-out-of-memory-in-golang/23235489?noredirect=1#comment35620413_23235489)(out of memory)

Comment: @clinyong, but [you was given an explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23235489/720999) already (and you've marked it as accepted). Supposedly you've failed to follow that advice. Post a minimal code example somewhere (pastebin.com etc).

Comment: @clinyong, to reiterate, `io.Copy()` does nothing more than reading data *in small chunks* from the `io.Reader` it was given and shoveling it at `io.Writer` passed to it. Hence if you get an OOM error, your data most probably *accumulates* at the writer, and your task is to find out why. Excessive mindless buffering is the one quite plausible reason.

Comment: @clinyong, could you please share your io.Pipe code. My io.Pipe code hanging and not responding. I am trying to upload 3 GB to file to server.